# using LONGTEXT as a variable to create a SELECT string causes an issue

Tags: mysql

I have a sql select statement that is over 540 characters within a stored procedure

I have placed it ino a variable called `l_final_query` of type `LONGTEXT`

Now, when i execute this query as:

```
PREPARE stmt7 FROM @l_final_query;
EXECUTE stmt7;
```

It fails. However, when i start cutting out the last order by clause of the sql, it works. I have had issues in the past with size of variables used to be executed and had work arounds. But now i dont have a woraround. I tried to place the `order by`  clause in another varaible `l_final_query2`, and concat this with the big select, but that also does not work.

This is the sql  that is attached to the variable and is executed. I have included the order by clause:

```
set @l_final_query = concat("SELECT a.project_code as projectCode, a.project_name as  projectName, a.project_creation_date as projectCreationDate, a.project_end_date as projectEndDate, a.project_status as projectStatus, count(c.project_code) as num from projects a inner join ", l_table_name, " b on a.project_name like concat(\"%\",b.expertise_desc,\"%\") OR a.project_description like concat(\"%\",b.expertise_desc,\"%\") left join project_ids c on c.project_code = a.project_code group by a.project_code order by a.project_status, a.project_creation_date desc");
```

Comment: Hope you have framed a valid query. But still, it would be good to see what it is and what the error stacktrace is.

Comment: Can you have a look and ket me know,

Comment: I am not sure if it is really a lengthy query issue. For a cross check, try with these changes: *`1.`* Remove *`as`* key words. *`2.`* Remove or shorten *`column aliases`*. *`3.`* Include *`order by xxx`* after this changes.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `varchar` data type can take 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions as per their manual. Dont think longtext is at all required. Can you try with only varchar?

Also, please show the SQL commands and the attempts like concatenation you have attempted for people to look at and point out any other issues.